# disconnected Dalvik machine while debugging broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, debugging, broadcastreceiver, dalvik, android-broadcast

I try to debug broadcast receiver which is detecting if any applicaion is deleted or added. But DVM disconnected until I install new app and control the broadcastreceiver that is detecting added applications. I found some solutions for the debugging. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html

but I couldn't use for real development devices.

any help?

Comment: Is the process being debugged stopping?  Does logcat show anything at the time of disconnection?

Comment: there is no warning in logcat. I try to detect new added applcaitons.There is an error. So I start to debug and I install an app. But until I install, it disconnects and I couldn't control the method.